# Dimensionality reduction for real time data

Tags: python

I was looking for this for days and couldn't find it, unfortunately.

I am working on high supervised dimensionality data (**50 features**, **2 classes**). I tried features selection using several techniques, but it didn't lead to better separation.

What I hope to get help is if there is any supervised dimensionality reduction method that I can get a projection matrix or matrices from to multiply it by the new incoming point (of 50 features) to project it and use the separation from this projection.

So in summary :

- I would get the projection from X records. Each labeled with 50 features
- Getting a projection matrix that I can use to transform new point (if reduction made good separation).

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: What is your data? Text classification? Did you try PCA, EFA, LSA, etc?

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.